# sift command not working Ubuntu version 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I'm using the siftDemoV4 for a sift program, but I cannot get the 'sift' command line argument working.Whenever I use the argument:

```
sift <Large.pgm> resultsfile.key
```

It instead asks me this:

```
The program 'sift' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-guiqwt
```

Which is a gui for something that does not pertain to this whatsoever.
Can someone explain how i can use the file needed?

Here are the readme docs for the files used for it : http://ecee.colorado.edu/~siewerts/extra/ecen5043/ecen5043_code/siftDemoV4/README

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 if that is necessary info

Comment: Have you tried to install `python-guiqwt` as it is suggested in the error?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work. All it does is bring up new window that doesn't pertain to what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change to the folder with the demo, for example: 
 `cd Donwloads/siftDemoV4`.

Then run it: `./sift <Large.pgm >resultsfile.key`. 
It's important to use `./`, which tells Ubuntu to run the binary from the current folder.